# Autocomplete in swift with select item and pass object

Tags: swift

I have seen many examples and tutorials about setting up autocomplete in swift. Mostly related to the search bar. But they do not include how to select the item in the drop-down and close the table view. Once you select the item how do you get access to the entire object. Also most data is coming from REST based API. Finally the search autocomplete should be incorporated with the existing view components.

Looking for examples or tutorials that address

- adding search autocomplete to existing view
- drop down data based on REST API. search term passed to API. Data includes entire object, not just name.
- select item from drop-down and get entire object
- hide table components and if necessary hide search components.

Comment: Every time you fetch data through API whenever you press searchbar right ?

Comment: Yes. Search as you type. Make API call after every letter. More advanced is to put a timer so only search after a pause in tying.